# Trigonometric functions - finding solutions

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

> Find the general solution for the equation:
>   $$\sin x + 2\sin2x - \sin3x = 3$$

Approach:
Well using the identity of $\sin a - \sin b $, I merged together $\sin x - \sin3x$
And as $\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x$, I got up till here:
$$2\sin x(2\cos x - \cos 2x) = 3$$

Edit:

> Considering $\sin x - \sin 3x = -2\cos 2x\sin x$
>   The equation becomes:
>   $$-2\cos 2x\sin x+2\sin 2x = 3$$
>   $$(-2\sin x)\cos 2x +2\sin 2x = 3$$
>   The maximum value of the equation $asinx + bcosx$ is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$
>   Using this in here: (considering $b = -2\sin x$ and $a = 2$)
>   $$3 \leq \sqrt{4\sin^2 x + 4}$$
>   $$3/2 \leq \sqrt{1 + sin^2x}$$
>   Obviously cannot happen as maximum value of $\sqrt{1 + sin^2x}$ is $\sqrt2$

Comment: Use $sinx=\sqrt{1-cos^2x}$, isolate the square-root-term and square the equality.

Comment: @Peter I do believe there to be an easier way to do this. This method will make the question way too long.

Comment: Robert's answer shows that the exercise is not easy.

Comment: @Peter I just found an easier method. Simplifies the question much more.

Comment: Ok, please show it.

Comment: @Peter Show it in as an answer or should I just edit?

Comment: I would prefer editing.

Comment: We have no solutions by a nice complex-analytic argument.

Comment: I do not understand the last step in the edit. But anyway, the right side cannot exceed $\sqrt{8}$, so the idea seems to work.

Comment: @Peter Well take 4 common, leaving $1+\sin^2x$ which is equal to $\cos^2x$ Thus we have $\sqrt{4cos^2x}$

Comment: $1-sin^2x=cos^2x$, not $1+sin^2x=cos^2x$

Comment: @Peter Oh true... Well it's still valid. maximum value of $\sqrt{\sin^2 x + 1}$ is $\sqrt{2}$ which is still less than 1.5

Comment: Look at my comment, I got the contradiction in a similar way.

Comment: @Peter Squaring it would have proven much more difficult as we would have to square a term in the form $(a + b + c)$

Answer (score 3):

By setting $z=e^{ix}\in S^1$, the given equation can be written as:
$$ \Im\left(z+2z^2-z^3\right) = 3 \tag{1}$$
that implies:
$$ \left\|z+2z^2-z^3\right\| = \left\| 2+\frac{1}{z}-z \right\|\geq 3\tag{2}$$
but that cannot happen since:
$$ \left\| 2+\frac{1}{z}-z \right\| = \left\| 2-2i\sin x\right\|\leq 2\sqrt{2} < 3,\tag{3} $$
so there are no real solutions.

Comment: Sorry but in the first step, what is that thingy in the starting? Looks like a 'J'.

Comment: @Gummybears: it stands for *imaginary part*. Have you studied complex numbers?

Comment: By the way, this proof just uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality like yours.

Comment: Yes I have studied complex numbers. Just never studied that symbol. Always used Im(z) to represent the imaginary part.

Comment: Ok, just a notation matter, $\Im(z)$ stands for $\operatorname{Im}(z)$.

Comment: Hmmmm... Where did the inequality appear from? Lost you there in the second step. And also, you took $z^2$ as a common factor, where did that factor disappear?

Comment: @Gummybears: everything follows from $\sin x = \Im(e^{ix})$, so $\sin(2x)=\Im(z^2)$ and so on.

Comment: @Gummybears: moreover, $z$ is a complex number with modulus one, so $\|z^2\|=1$ can be factored away.

Comment: What's $S^1$ stand for?

Comment: @GFauxPas: the unit circle.

Comment: Ohhhh.... the the fact that the modulus is 1 clears it up.

Comment: In the last step, where did $2 - 2\sin x$ appear from?

Comment: @Gummybears: if $z=e^{ix}$, then $\frac{1}{z}-z = 2i\sin x$.

Comment: Ohhh Okay. In the end it comes out to the same inequality. Really shows how closely complex numbers are trigonometry are related.

Answer (score 1):

By using the trigonometric identities:

$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\sin(3x) = 3\sin(x)-4\sin^{3}(x),$$ we have

$$\sin(x) +4\sin(x)\cos(x) -3\sin(x) + 4\sin^3(x) = 3 \implies \cos(x) = \frac{3 + 2\sin(x) -4\sin^3(x)}{4\sin(x)}.$$

By squaring the equation, the solutions are kept. Hence,

$$1-\sin^2(x) = \frac{16\sin^6(x)-16\sin^4(x)-24\sin^3(x)+4\sin^2(x)+12\sin(x) +9}{16\sin^2(x)}.$$

Take $y = \sin(x)$. Thus,

$$(1-y^2) = \frac{16y^6-16y^4-24y^3+4y^2 +12y+9}{16y^2}$$ $$\implies 16y^6-24y^3-12y^2 +12y+9 =0,$$ which has no real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are no real solutions.  $s = \sin(x)$ must satisfy
$16s^6-24s^3-12s^2+12s+9=0$, which has no real root.

Comment: How did you reach that conclusion though?

Comment: I used Maple's **sturm** procedure to count the real roots.